# [Rails]Use AJAX to render new comments on post page only works for the first time

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to use AJAX to display the latest comment underneath posts but it only works for the first comment. If I try to send the second comment I get `Identifier has already been declared`.

[JS errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6NCbp.png)

#### comments_controller.rb

```rb
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
    def create
        @comment = Current.user.comments.build(comment_params)
        @article = Article.find(params[:article_id])
        @comments = @article.comments.includes(:user).order(created_at: :asc)

      respond_to do |format|
        if @comment.save
          format.js
          format.html { redirect_to article_path(comment.article), flash: { success: t('defaults.message.created', item: Comment.model_name.human) } }
        else
          format.js
          format.html { redirect_to article_path(comment.article), flash: { danger: t('defaults.message.not_created', item: Comment.model_name.human) } }
        end
      end
    end

    def destroy
      @comment = Current.user.comments.find(params[:id])
      @article = Article.find(params[:article_id])
      respond_to do |format|
        @comment.destroy
          format.js
          format.html { redirect_to article_path(@article), flash: { success: t('defaults.message.destroyed', item: Comment.model_name.human) } }
      end
    end
    
    private

    def comment_params
        params.require(:comment).permit(:body).merge(article_id: params[:article_id])
    end
end
```

I am rendering comment form and comments under the post.

#### articles/show.html.erb

```rb
<% content_for(:title, @article.title) %>
<h1><%= t('.title') %></h1>
<h2><%= @article.title %></h2>
<p><%= simple_format(@article.body) %></p>
<%= render 'articles/crud', { article: @article } %>
<br>
<h3 class="mt-3">Leave a comment!</h3>
<%= render 'comments/form', { article: @article, comment: @comment } %>
<br>
<%= render 'comments/comments', { comments: @comments } %>
```

#### comments/create.js.erb

```js
// Clear existing commentErrors and commentTemplate
const commentErrors = document.querySelector('.error_messages');
if (commentErrors) {
commentErrors.remove();
}
<% if @comment.errors.any? %>
  // Handle error case
  const newCommentBody = document.getElementById('new_comment');
  const errorMessages = '<%= j(render('shared/error_messages', object: @comment)) %>';
  newCommentBody.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', errorMessages);
<% else %>
  // Render comment template
  const commentTemplate = '<%= j(render('comments/comment', article: @article, comment: @comment)) %>';
  const commentContainer = document.getElementById('js-comment-container');
  commentContainer.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', commentTemplate);
  // Clear comment form
  const newCommentBody = document.getElementById('js-new-comment-body');
  newCommentBody.value = '';
<% end %>
```

Also, error messages do not show up if i submit an empty comment in spite of having it in my comment form but it works if i render it in  `create.js.erb`

#### comments/_form.html.erb

```rb
<%= form_with model: [article, comment], local: false, id: 'new_comment' do |form| %>
  # not working here but in js
  <% comment.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
    <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
      <%= message %>
      <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"></button>
    </div>
  <% end %>
  <div class="mb-3">
    <%= form.label :body %>
    <%= form.text_area :body, class: 'form-control', id: 'js-new-comment-body' %>
  </div>
  <div class="text-end">
    <%= form.submit class: 'btn btn-primary btn-sm' %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

I would like to be able to send more than one comments without the JS error.
So far only the first comment works and the JS error shows up upon second try.
But I have only declared the variable once in my code so I don't understand why it is not working.
I would also like the error messages in my comment form to work on empty comments.
Right now it is rendered from `create.js.erb` but the code with regard to error messages is exactly the same as the one in the `_comment.html.erb`.
I don't understand why only one of them works.